# R/Shiny: Populate SelectInput Options using Headers From Uploaded File

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I'm trying to build a page using R Shiny that has:

- A File Widget for uploading CSV files
- A SelectInput component

I'd like to use these as follows:

- Upon uploading a valid CSV file, populate the SelectInput whose options are the headers from the CSV file, the first header being the default selected

I've tried various forms of `observe()` and `observeEvent()` so far, but have had no success in getting this even close. Any suggestions you may have would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option -

```
library(shiny)

#Sample data
#write.csv(mtcars, 'data.csv', row.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('file', 'Upload csv file'),
  uiOutput('dropdown')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  output$dropdown <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput('cols', 'Select Column', names(data()))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]